# What are goldstone variables?

Tags: topological-phase

Pretty straightforward question (I hope). I am an experimentalist. I used to work in Nuclear Experiment (now I work in membrane biophysics). While reading about topological transitions in liquid crystals I cam across the term, and a cursory Google search turned up nothing other than some obscure (at least to me) HEP theory papers without definitions. Is the term just jargon? Do these variables have a specific physical definition?

Thanks.

EDIT: I was fairly sleep deprived when I wrote this. I apologize if it sounded like I was implying that HEP theory is inherently obscure to a fault (on the contrary, I hold great respect for my fellow physicists in HEP! - but I don't "talk the talk" so to speak). I was simply having some trouble finding a definition I could understand. I figured somebody on SE might be able to explain it to me in terms that might be easier to understand on a more conceptual level (perhaps prompting more questions and curiosities on my part).

Thanks again.

Comment: Did you try [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstone_boson) first? They are massless excitations associated with spontaneous symmetry breaking. If SSB does not ring any bells with you,  learn about it first, before wasting time on Goldstone modes.

Comment: I did, but was initially confused about calling them "angles" as well. SSB is familiar to me only at a basic conceptual level. I was hoping to find more academic sources dealing with liquid crystal systems (though it seems SSB is a fairly abstracted phenomenon) - I have since found a few. Going back to WP helped now that I have a slightly better understanding of the term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the fact that a physicist specializing in the subfield AB doesn't understand papers in the subfield CD doesn't make the latter "obscure". At most, they are esoteric.

Second, terms such as the "Goldstone variable" are obviously a part of jargon – a portion of vocabulary that is only being used by a special subset of the English speakers (e.g. high-energy theoretical physicists) but its being a jargon doesn't mean that the words are ill-defined.

Third, the term Goldstone variable is exactly equivalent to the [Goldstone boson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstone_boson) when the variable is bosonic – i.e. basically commuting or Grassmann-even. The Goldstone boson is a boson associated with a broken generator of a symmetry that may be proven to be massless by the Goldstone theorem.

[The word "variable" is sometimes being used](https://scholar.google.cz/scholar?q=%22goldstone%20variable%22&hl=en&lr=&btnG=Search) instead of a "boson" because these papers typically talk about cases when these symmetries are actually fermionic, not bosonic – usually exotic fermionic symmetries that violate the usual spin-statistics relationship (they are fermionic but integer-spin), and therefore can't appear in realistic theories of particle physics.

They are Grassmann-odd or anti-commuting. The word "boson" would clearly be a contradiction. This isn't taught to students in some standard way so the authors of the papers may take different solutions to these problems, i.e. call them either "Goldstinos" or "Goldstone variables" to avoid the word "boson" while making it clear that the logic is the same as it is for Goldstone bosons. These supersymmetry-like, fermionic symmetries may be broken and a proof similar to that of the Goldstone theorem guarantees that there exist corresponding massless fermionic fields, the Goldstone variables.